Is there a way of homing in on the eigenstates of the TDSE in 2 dimensions using a numerical method?
I have written a program which calculates the evolution of the time dependent Schrodinger equation (TDSE) on a 100 X 100 grid of points using the following approximation for del-squared
$$\psi_{x-1,y}+\psi_{x+1,y}+\psi_{x,y-1}+\psi_{x,y+1}-4\psi_{x,y}$$
Each iteration is calculated using Runge-Kutta4. To simulate an infinite potential well, psi is set to zero at the edges.
Is there any way of modifying the algorithm analogous to adding a 'damping' term which will cause the simulation to home in on the nearest (?) eigenstate?

What is the meaning of "homing in" in international english ?

Get closer and closer to the eigenstate with each iteration.

What's the TDSE?

Time dependent Schrodinger equation.

Why use time evolution if you are interested in finding eigenstates? These are two separate problems
